# Find out the Duplicate Records in Sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In our application, we have some tables storing staff data. I need to find out whether the same office is allocated to a staff member multiple times. How can I figure this out in SQL Server?

I have tried below query but it didn't give me the correct solution.

```
SELECT DISTINCT STAFFID, officeid
FROM [stafftable]
WHERE rowstatus = 'A'
GROUP BY STAFFID, officeid
HAVING COUNT(staffid) > 1
    AND COUNT(officeid) > 1
ORDER BY STAFFID, officeid
```

It returns the staff members allocated to different offices also.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a distinct if you are using `group by`. Remove that distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STAFFID, officeid ORDER BY STAFFID)
    FROM dbo.stafftable
    WHERE rowstatus = 'A'
) t
WHERE t.RowNum > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COUNT(*)` to count all rows in each group:

```
SELECT STAFFID, officeid
FROM [stafftable]
WHERE rowstatus = 'A'
GROUP BY STAFFID, officeid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY STAFFID, officeid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;With cte 
as (
select * row_number() over(partition by STAFFID, officeid )as count from stafftable
where rowstatus = 'A'
)
select * from cte where count > 1
```